# Failed to create designer 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTapStrip'

Tags: html, telerik

Tengo una pagina web y estoy creando un nuevo elemento (Formulario Web Forms) en C#, estoy mandando a llamar Telerik.Web.UI.dll para crear el objeto `RadTabStrip`

```
      <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server"> 

      </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Failed to create designer 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTapStrip, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.2.701.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'
```

Comment: Podrias dar un poco mas de información sobre tu problema?

Comment: Ya lo especifique de una mejor manera